# Saving user information in MySql with NodeJs

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js, web

I want to make a register form. After the "Submit" button is pressed the script opens my MySql database and inserts a new row in the "Users" table.
Everything works, except the browser can't interpret the NodeJs `require` function.
Some other posts said to use browserify but I want to know if this can be done without other programs.

My code:

**register.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title></title>
<script src = "index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src = "register.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "register.css">
</head>

<body>
<form name = "registerForm" method = "post">
<p id = "fillRule">Username must contain lower or uppercase or _! Fill in all boxes except the job! Pass must contain small and uppercase letters and its lenght must be at least 6 char, max 10!</p>
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type = "text" id = "username" name = "username" onchange = "checkUser()"> <br/>
<label for="firstname">Firstname:</label>
<input type = "text" id = "firstname" name = "firstame" onchange = "checkFirst()"> <br/>
<label for="lastname">Lastname:</label>
<input type = "text" id = "lastname" name = "lastname" onchange = "checkLast()"> <br/>
<label for="job">Your job:</label>
<input type = "text" id = "job" name = "job" onchange="checkJob()"> <br/>
<label for="pass">Password:</label>
<input type = "text" id = "pass" name = "pass" onchange = "checkPass()">        <br/>
<label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
<input type = "email" id = "mail" name = "mail" onchange = "checkMail()"> <br/>
<input type = "button" value = "send" id = "gomb" disabled = "disabled"   onclick = "registerButtonClick()">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

**index.js**

```
    //export {addUser};

    // String formatting
    if (!String.format) {
    String.format = function(format) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        return format.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function(match, number) {
            return typeof args[number] != 'undefined'
                ? args[number]
                : match
                ;
        });
    };
}
//

var mysql = require("mysql");

function createConnection(hostName, userName, passwd, db)
{
    const con = mysql.createConnection({
        host: hostName,
        user: userName,
        password: passwd,
        database: db
    });
    return con;
}

 function openConnection(con)
{
    con.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error connecting to Db');
            return;
        }
        console.log('Connection established');
    });
}

function executeFullSelect(con, tableName)
{
    const statement = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName + ";";
    con.query(statement, function(err, rows)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            throw err;
        }
        console.log("Data received from " + tableName + ".\n");
        console.log(rows);
        /*for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
        {
            console.log(rows[i].UserName);
        }*/
    });
}

function insert(con, userName,firstName, lastName, job, mail, passwd)
{
    const statement = String.format("call newUser(\"{0}\", \"{1}\", \"{2}\", \"{3}\", \"{4}\", \"{5}\");", userName, firstName, lastName, job, mail, passwd);
    con.query(statement, function(err, rows)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            console.log("Error at insert");
            return 0;
        }

        console.log(userName + " was successfully added:)");
        return 1;
    })
}

function closeConnection(con)
{
    con.end(function (err) {});
}

function addUser(userName, firstName, lastName, job, mail ,passwd)
{
    const con = createConnection("localhost", "root", "micimacko", "users");
    openConnection(con);
    if (!insert(con, userName, firstName, lastName, job, mail ,passwd))
    {
        closeConnection(con);
        return 0;
    }
    closeConnection(con);
    return 1;
}
```

**register.js**

```
function registerButtonClick()
{
    const userName = document.forms["registerForm"]["username"].value;
    const firstName = document.forms["registerForm"]["firstname"].value;
    const lastName = document.forms["registerForm"]["lastname"].value;
    const job = document.forms["registerForm"]["job"].value;
    const mail = document.forms["registerForm"]["mail"].value;
    const pass = document.forms["registerForm"]["pass"].value;

    if (addUser(userName, firstName, lastName, job, mail, pass))
    {
        alert("added");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you including server-side code on the web page?

Comment: Well that was my question. How should I do it correctly?

Comment: By running the node.js code in node.js and not trying to include it on the web page. They are completely separate things. You do have node.js set up as the server?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen, it's 2017 and today nobody actually knows for sure which JavaScript code should go where. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect to your MySQL database directly from the browser. Node is a separate enviroment to the Javascript interpreter in the browser, it runs in the server, and it is there that you should connect to the database. It is fairly easy to create an HTTP server with node:

```js
var http = require('http');
var port = 3000;

const requestHandler = function (request, response) {  
 console.log(request.url)
 response.end('Hello Node.js Server!');
};

const server = http.createServer(requestHandler);

server.listen(port, function (err) {  
  if (err) {
    return console.log('something bad happened', err)
  }
  console.log('server is listening on ' + port);
});
```

You would have, however, to handle routing (*i.e.* executing different operations according to the path requested in the URL) directly by hand,
so I’d recommend you to read about some Web framework for Node, like Expressjs⁽¹⁾ for instance.

In Express you could do something like:

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/hello', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello');
});

app.get('/world', function (req, res) {
  res.send('World');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
});
```

Which would give you `https://localhost:3000/hello` and `https://localhost:3000/world`, one returning “Hello” and the other returning “World.”

As for the communication between the browser and the server, you may use AJAX. I would recommend you to use fetch,⁽²⁾ but you can use `jQuery.ajax`⁽³⁾ also, or really any other solution, or even directly call the browser’s `XMLHttpRequest`.⁽⁴⁾

⁽¹⁾ https://expressjs.com

⁽²⁾ Fetch is a new standard for web requests in the browser, which you can already use through this polyfill: https://github.com/github/fetch

⁽³⁾ http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

⁽⁴⁾ http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#ajax